# Getting associated data from max column with multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, Orders and OrderDetails. I would like to create an SQL query that retrieves the OrderID, Unit Cost and Process Date for orders with the latest processed T-Shirts for each user.

I have created a very simplified version of my tables in this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ee888/1).

From my google searches, most of which ended up here on SO, I have managed to figure out SQL to get the associated unit cost for the latest processed order of T-shirts per order, but I'm not sure how to further condense it from here to be for each user and still maintain the correct unit cost and process dates. I know I can't use `MAX` and `GROUP BY` and I can't work out how to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (like how I did the first part in the SQL fiddle) when the `UserID` and `ProcessDate` reside in different tables.

For the dataset in the SQL fiddle, the output I would be looking for would be

```
| UserID    | OrderID   | UnitCost  | ProcessDate   |
|--------   |---------  |---------- |-------------  |
| 1         | 2         | 3         | 2018-03-01    |
| 2         | 3         | 1         | 2018-04-01    |
| 3         | 5         | 3         | 2018-06-01    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above query output is perfectly fine just the case is correlated subquery gets executed everytime for each row which is quite a overhead and in case of large data there will be performance issue.

I have changed the subquery into join which may be helpful.

```
SELECT O.UserID
     , O.OrderID
     , OD.UnitCost
     , OD.ProcessDate
  FROM Orders O 
  left 
  JOIN OrderDetails OD 
   ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID 
  left 
  join 
     ( SELECT o2.userid
           , max(od2.processdate) newdate 
        FROM Orders o2 
        JOIN OrderDetails od2
          ON o2.OrderId = od2.OrderId
       WHERE od2.Product = 'T-Shirts' 
       group 
          by o2.userid
     ) temp
    on O.userid = temp.userid
 WHERE OD.Product = 'T-Shirts' 
   and OD.processdate = temp.newdate
 ORDER 
    BY OD.OrderDetailID;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was just in the middle of experiencing the performance issues with the other answer! I am currently running the query on the live data and so far it's taken 25 minutes to run that query! Once it's finished, I will try your query and check that it gets the same results and see how it compares performancewise! Thanks :)

Comment: This version reduced the query time from 30 minutes down to under 2 seconds! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can select the "latest" order for each user using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT O.UserID, O.OrderID, OD.UnitCost, OD.ProcessDate
FROM OrderDetails OD LEFT JOIN
     Orders O
     ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
WHERE OD.Product = 'T-Shirts' AND
      o.OrderID = (SELECT MAX(o2.OrderId)
                   FROM Orders o2
                   WHERE o2.UserID = o.UserID
                  )
ORDER BY OD.OrderDetailID;
```

This assumes that the latest order is the one with the largest `OrderId`.

EDIT:

Actually, the above happens to work on your data, because the largest order id for each user has t-shirts.  However, you explicitly say that you want the latest order with t-shirts, so that requires a slight modification:

```
SELECT O.UserID, O.OrderID, OD.UnitCost, OD.ProcessDate
FROM Orders O LEFT JOIN
     OrderDetails OD 
     ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
WHERE OD.Product = 'T-Shirts' AND
      o.OrderID = (SELECT MAX(o2.OrderId)
                   FROM Orders o2 JOIN
                        OrderDetails od2
                        ON o2.OrderId = od2.OrderId
                   WHERE od2.Product = 'T-Shirts' AND
                         o2.UserID = o.UserID
                  )
ORDER BY OD.OrderDetailID;
```

Or, if you want to go by process date:

```
SELECT O.UserID, O.OrderID, OD.UnitCost, OD.ProcessDate
FROM Orders O LEFT JOIN
     OrderDetails OD 
     ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
WHERE OD.Product = 'T-Shirts' AND
      od.ProcessDate = (SELECT od2.ProcessDate
                        FROM Orders o2 JOIN
                             OrderDetails od2
                             ON o2.OrderId = od2.OrderId
                        WHERE od2.Product = 'T-Shirts' AND
                              o2.UserID = o.UserID
                        ORDER BY od2.ProcessDate DESC
                        LIMIT 1
                       )
ORDER BY OD.OrderDetailID;
```

Comment: Why do you say all orders have t-shirts? There are a mix of t-shirts, shorts and shoes, but in the query I made, I already pulled out only t-shirts. I am working through to understand the answer in your post now! Thanks :)

Comment: @BenHolness . . . Poor phrasing on my part.  I fixed it.

Comment: Also, I don't think your query would fully work as you are using MAX(o2.OrderId), but this does not necessarily correlate to the last processed item, the date for which is in the OrderDetails table.

Comment: @BenHolness . . . All three of the queries in the answer match your desired results.

Comment: I have updated the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ee888/1) with extra data to help highlight where the first one doesn't work

Comment: The last query, going by process date, seems to work OK! I am now implementing it on the system with lots of real data, then I will know for sure that it is 100% and will mark it as solved, if you can remove the first two queries :) thanks!